# How do you save an Android application log to a file on a physical device?

Tags: android, logging

I want to know why my Android application service occasionally goes down (whether it's the OS killing it or a crasch) and therefore I want to save a log file on my phone. How can is this be done?

Comment: please help us with giving some references, tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you got two possibilities and normally the first one should help you finding already the reason for the crash without coding anything since the **logcat** should show up the error occurred that led to the service end.

**1) Using the logcat command**

Having `Log.i("your tag", "output text")` you can intercept those messages using the Android Eclipse plugin or by calling `adb logcat` from your command line, having your Android device connected and your service running.

See also http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logat

**2) Writing to stdout**

Using the `System.out.println("...")` command you can configure your device to write the stdout into a file:

```
adb shell stop
adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
adb shell start
```

See also http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#stdout

Obviously you have to spread a lot of debug output messages over your application, mainly at the critical points.

Good luck for finding the error!

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't both these options require that the device is connected to the computer running eclipse? I want to see the log produced after the device has been running in "production", i.e. while I'm carrying it around and using it normally.

Comment: Found a tool on the market called aLogCat which suits my needs.

Comment: The second options writes the log into a file on the device -- ``log.redirect-stdio``

Comment: Hi christain, am also trying to do the same, can you please help me by giving me some references.

Comment: Christian  can you give us a link or reference to the solution you found

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=alogcat&c=apps

Comment: @Gray sorry, this was 10 years ago so I don't really remember. Other than the comments above I'm afraid I can't help.