# Android: Redirecting Log.x() calls to a file?

Tags: android, logging

is it possible to log messages sent through Log.x(...) [x € d, i etc.] to a file? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you save an Android application log to a file on a physical device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101691/how-do-you-save-an-android-application-log-to-a-file-on-a-physical-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the adb shell you can do logcat > some_file

You can probably also issue this shell command from an application which has the necessary permission to read logs

Answer (score 0):

open the cmd prompt

set up the path of our platform tools in android sdk

eg:

```
c:\android-sdk\platformtools > adb logcat > log.txt
```

This is the command to store the log in a file:

`adb logcat > log.txt`