# how to get Logs and write them in files

Tags: android, logging

I want to write all logs displayed in logcat into a file when my application crashes (forced close) or else also.Is there ane way to get Logs programatically ? or is there ane way to know when my application crashed? 
  I dont want to use "adb logcat " command. Plz help me out

Comment: Refer this [Android logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging) and [How do I write outputs to the Log in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364811/how-do-i-write-outputs-to-the-log-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [microlog4android](http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/)

and also go through this question too [How do you save an Android application log to a file on a physical device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101691/how-do-you-save-an-android-application-log-to-a-file-on-a-physical-device)

Copied **"Lars Blumberg"** answer for your quick reference:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

Refer for more info: **[Viewing stdout and stderr](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#stdout)**

If you want write your own Log function, see this answer [Android Writing Logs to text File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209739/500725)